# Testing initial delay on CoroutineWorker with Dependencies

Tags: testing, delay, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager, coroutineworker

I know that WorkManager provides a work-testing artifact for test workers and we can use [TestListenableWorkerBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/testing/TestListenableWorkerBuilder) to test [CoroutineWorker](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/CoroutineWorker) (see this [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/testing-worker-impl) for more information). I found an [medium article](https://medium.com/@thefallen.class/unit-testing-workmanager-with-dependencies-8ffff7ef5476) by [Ian Roberts](https://medium.com/@thefallen.class) showing how to test CoroutineWorker with dependencies by creating your own WorkerFactory.

According to [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/integration-testing), we can test initial delays on Worker using TestDriver but nothing was said about testing delays, constraints etc on CoroutinesWork. Is there a way to perform such tests in CoroutineWorker using TestListenableWorkerBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

After watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bz0z694SrEE) (at 13:00) from the 2019 Android Dev Summit, I found the answer for this question:

1. When initializing `workManager` for test **(by `WorkManagerTestInitHelper.initializeTestWorkManager` method)**, we have to pass our custom `WorkerFactory` through the configuration step;
2. Setup your request worker as you normally would using the `OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder` method;
3. By default, all constraints for `Workmanager` instances in the test
   mode are unmet. Using an instance of `TestDriver`, we can mark those constraints as met.

Here's an example to summarize these above steps:

```
@Test
fun checkInitialDelay() {
    val config = Configuration.Builder()
        .setWorkerFactory(
            MyWorkFactory(myDependencies)
        )
        .setMinimumLoggingLevel(Log.DEBUG)
        .setExecutor(SynchronousExecutor())
        .build()
    // Initialize WorkManager
    WorkManagerTestInitHelper.initializeTestWorkManager(context, config)

    //setup the request work
    val request =
        OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<MyWork>()
            .setInitialDelay(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build()

    val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
    // Get the TestDriver
    val testDriver = WorkManagerTestInitHelper.getTestDriver(context)
    // Enqueue
    workManager.enqueue(request).result.get()
    // Tells the WorkManager test framework that initial delays are now met.
    testDriver?.setInitialDelayMet(request.id)
    // Get WorkInfo and outputData
    val workInfo = workManager.getWorkInfoById(request.id).get()

    // Assert
    assert(workInfo.state == WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED)
}
```